# Fragments navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragment-backstack

I need to create navigation of fragments like in Gmail app. It's like: we have one main fragment A, we can open another fragment (B,C,D...) from navigation drawer, and when we open new fragment, it`s open on top of main fragment, and when press back button, in all cases we come back to main fragment A, don't depend of count new opened fragments. It's seems, first main fragment A we use add method(int FragmentTransaction) without adding to fragment backStack. Then, next fragment B we use method add too, with adding to back stack. And when I need to open another one (Fragment C), I need to replace second fragment B. But, when I use method replace(), replaced all container, and main fragment A not showing when back button pressed from fragment C or B and app close. So, the question is: how to replace only fragment B or C, without losing fragment A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid solution would be to have two container framelayouts in your activity. The first one (which will below the other one) contains your fragment A. Everything you open will be added/replaced in the second container.

Another solution is to include the fragment A statically in your layout and have your container framelayout on top of it where you add your fragments B, C, D etc.

Comment: I try to make second solution. I added fragment A statically and create on top FrameLayout for another fragment. When I open new Fragment, I use  replace(), but face with problem: if I add new fragments to back stack, onBack pressed I have all opened earlier fragment, if I don't add to back stack, onBackpressed app close.

Comment: I think, I need to add to back stack only first Fragment from another(for example: B,C, D etc)

Comment: Yes Add to back Stack For only first Fragment

Answer (score 1):

open fragment Like this

```
HighlightFragment highlightFragment=new HighlightFragment(FirstReaderScreen.this); //Your fragment
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.LL_Fragment, highlightFragment) // LL_fragment is container
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

and in Activity OnBackPress

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } 
}
```

Comment: why, when I do addToBackStack(null), I've got crash NullPointerException?

Comment: It Works Fine For me Can You post Logcat